# REACT : pass a component to a function to that will implement component actions

Tags: reactjs

We're trying to build a generic user permission handler for a system. We're currently using REACT to build the components. I do not write the codes myself, so please bear with the "pseudocode" below as my way of explaining the problem. (I'm asking this myself because my team's developers do not know how to implement this either.)

The idea is to have two functions, checkPermissions() and applyPermissions(), that will manage all component behaviours based on the user's permissions. This includes, but not limited to, the following:

1. Deciding whether to display or hide a component.
2. Enabling or disabling a component.
3. Allowing the user to proceed with the action he attempted to perform (e.g. deleting a record, adding a record, etc.).
4. Displaying the message that will tell the user why the action attempted was cancelled.

The checkPermissions() function does all the data gathering and processing of the user permissions. Once it has acquired the necessary data, it will decide what will be the component's action/response/state and prepares that response data to the applyPermissions() function, Then, the applyPermissions() function will perform the response. This means that the component itself will be passed to the checkPermissions() function (along with the user data) and then again to the applyPermissions() function (along with the response data) wherein the supposed response of the passed component will be implemented.

Now, our problem is whether this is possible at all with REACT -- to have a component be created/initialised inside one file and then have some of its specific behaviours and responses be handled on another file.

(Please see concept below.)

```
UIComponent tabMyContacts;
UIComponent tabMyMessages;
UIComponent tabMyRequests;

// some declarations of the UI component

// in this example, the following lines checks whether 
// these 3 components will be visible/displayed
// based on the user's permissions

checkPermissions(tabMyContacts, appuserId);
checkPermissions(tabMyMessages, appuserId);
checkPermissions(tabMyRequests, appuserId);

------ separate file ------

function checkPermissions(component, appuserId){

    //some process here to get the user permissions data
    //some process to prepare the responses based on the acquired data

    applyPermissions(component, componentResponse, componentResponseValue);

}

function applyPermissions(component, componentResponse, componentResponseValue) {

// componentResponseValue -- in this example, the possible values are TRUE or FALSE, 
//but this variable can also contain the prompt message or some other info

if (componentResponse == "SET_VISIBLE"){
        component.setVisible( componentResponseValue );
}
else if (componentResponse == "SET_ENABLED"){
        component.setEnabled( componentResponseValue ); 
}


}
```

The idea is here is to not have the user permission handler be written repeatedly in every component that we add because we intend to implement a user permission system where the permissions (View, Edit, Add, Remove) are set to EVERY SINGLE component -- that is, the user permissions are set for down to each field, each button, etc. -- so you can imagine just how tedious it would be set the states per component and every single time a new one is added or modified.

I need to know if something like this is possible with REACT and there are alternative implementations that accomplishes the same goal.

Comment: This is a very convoluted question but I get the gist. I would try looking into Higher-Order Components as they seemingly solve the same problem that you have which is to share functionality across components. Check out the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html .

Comment: @KarolisRamanauskas We will check it out. Thanks!